# server-side pdfmake libraries not recognised

Tags: javascript, libraries, pdfmake

I am trying to use pdfmake on server-side following these instructions
https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/getting-started/server-side/

What I've done is:

1. I run npm install pdfmake
2. I download the pdfmake.js and vfs_fonts.js libs and place them in the the project file
3. I add the basic html and javascript needed and my code looks like this

```
<html>
    <head>       
        <script src='test\libs\pdfmake.js'></script> 
        <script src='test\libs\vfs_fonts.js'></script> 
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-8 ">
            <button id="download_pdf" onclick="downloadfunction()" download>Download Button</button>
        </div>
    </body>

    <script>
        function downloadfunction() {

            var docDefinition = {
                content: [
                    {text: "Hello"}                
                ]
            };
            pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
        };
    </script>
</html>
```

4. but when I run it, I get this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: pdfMake is not defined

Why the pdfMake is not recognized? Am I missing any step?

Also, when I include the libs like this:

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.70/pdfmake.js'></script> 
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.70/vfs_fonts.js'></script>
```

it works, but I want to do it offline and get the libs directly from my project

Thank you!